# Global surface water/ How to compare area of latest image to older images and generate histogram

Tags: google-earth-engine, area, statistics, histogram, water

Based on the Global surface water script, I would like to compare the water decreasing per year and plot a histogram for the area lost per year. I know that there is a dataset that goes by monthly steps. I am new to coding, so hopefully, someone can assist me.

Script retrieved from link below and changed to my location.
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_global_surface_water_03

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Asset List
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var gsw = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_4/GlobalSurfaceWater");
var occurrence = gsw.select('occurrence');
var change = gsw.select("change_abs");

var roi = /* color: #00ffff */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-114.8504736421902, 36.03010864180188],
          [-114.7351171968777, 36.0034499383638],
          [-114.2462255953152, 35.99456170017402],
          [-113.7847998140652, 36.025666150795224],
          [-114.3231298921902, 36.6495790805719],
          [-114.8889257906277, 36.132216765344175]]]);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Constants
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var VIS_OCCURRENCE = {
    min:0,
    max:100,
    palette: ['red', 'blue']
};
var VIS_CHANGE = {
    min:-50,
    max:50,
    palette: ['red', 'black', 'limegreen']
};
var VIS_WATER_MASK = {
  palette: ['white', 'black']
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Calculations
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Create a water mask layer, and set the image mask so that non-water areas are transparent.
var water_mask = occurrence.gt(90).mask(1);

// Generate a histogram object and print it to the console tab.
var histogram = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: change,
  region: roi,
  scale: 30,
  minBucketWidth: 10
});
histogram.setOptions({
  title: 'Histogram of surface water change intensity.'
});
print(histogram);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Initialize Map Location
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Uncomment one of the following statements to center the map on
// a particular location.

Map.setCenter(-114.4439795015652, 36.12393236330946, 8);  // Lake Mead

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Map Layers
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: occurrence.updateMask(occurrence.divide(100)),
  name: "Water Occurrence (1984-2022)",
  visParams: VIS_OCCURRENCE,
  shown: false
});
Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: change,
  visParams: VIS_CHANGE,
  name: 'occurrence change intensity'
});
```

Comment: What's the question? Do you have an error?

Comment: I think that is not possible with this product. You only can consider the "Absolute change in occurrence between two epochs: 1984-1999 vs 2000-2021" (only two values). Read again the information in this link: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GSW1_4_GlobalSurfaceWater#bands and in this one https://storage.googleapis.com/global-surface-water/downloads_ancillary/DataUsersGuidev2021.pdf